# The phrase "too simple"

Tags: phrase-meaning, academia

I've seen three different peer reviewers criticize parts of scientific manuscripts as being "too simple", with little elaboration as to what changes are desired or what it means to be "too simple". For example, a reviewer told me that a method section of one of my papers "was too simple and not clear".

To my ear, "too simple" sounds like a mistake, but is it a feature of some dialect, such as Indian English? Or is it perhaps an established custom among non-native speakers, like beginning a question with "How to"? And what does "too simple" mean, anyway? Maybe "simplistic" is meant, but my best guess based on context is something more like "too short" or "insufficiently detailed".

Comment: *Too simple* is idiomatic in native English. (And *simplistic* ***does*** mean *insufficiently detailed*.)

Comment: I have a hard time believing that "too simple" would sound unidiomatic to any native speaker (it's the same syntax as saying "it's too hot outside", which I would imagine that most learners would be familiar with too). But is that the real issue? Shouldn't you ask a question on Academia instead on either what the reviewers want from your paper (as [this question has](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/126547/56207)) or how to ask the reviewers for better feedback?

Comment: None of the 8 dictionaries I've checked in gives a 'simplistic' sense for 'simple', and I'd agree that 'too simple' for 'insufficiently detailed, unsophisticated' is non-standard. That's not to say it's not used. // Of course, 'too simple' = 'too easy' is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are looking at the wrong word. Merriam-Webster defines [**simplistic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simplistic) as "excessively simple or simplified." *Excessively simple* is synonymous with *too simple*.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Of course, in say _These questions are too simple/simplistic for undergraduates._ But _not_ in say _Your essay is too simple._ Dictionaries must be handled with due care. They don't explain everything.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the descriptive and everyday use of language, I understand *your essay is* ***too simple*** to mean exactly the same thing as *your essay is* ***simplistic***. Surely you can't be arguing that you don't understand what the reviewers were trying to communicate in their criticism—or even that it's not phrasing that would be used in most regular contexts? I would go further and argue (if I really wanted to debate the point) that *too simple* is ***more*** idiomatic than *simplistic* in this very context. (Even though I equate their meaning.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford I'd say it certainly shouldn't be used by 'peer reviewers [to] criticize parts of scientific manuscripts'. The following 'By Richard Nordquist Updated February 12, 2020](https://www.thoughtco.com/simple-and-simplistic-1689612)
... The words _simple_ and _simplistic_ share the same root word, but their meanings are quite different. The adjective simple means plain, easy, ordinary, or uncomplicated. A simple solution to a problem is usually a good solution. In addition, simple is sometimes used as a synonym for naive or unsophisticated. ...

Comment: The adjective simplistic is a pejorative word meaning overly simplified—that is, characterized by extreme and often misleading simplicity. A simplistic solution to a problem is usually a bad solution. _So, with regard to crits of scientific articles, simple language can hardly be considered erroneous, while simplistic, dumbed-down treatments, certainly can. The 'simple may be used as a synonym for unsophisticated' sense would be non-default here, so incorrect according to Gricean maxims._

Comment: @Laurel I agree that the syntax is clear. I'm asking about semantics. Academia.SE is probably not the best place to ask if an expression is foreign, even if it appears in a peer review.

Answer (score 2):

I might be incorrect, but I think it means (depending on the context)that it needs more to it; more detail. But that is used when your professor/teacher annotates your essay and might tell you to make revisions.

Comment: Most likely what the reviewers actually meant to say was that the manuscript was [**simplistic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simplistic). However, most people don't make such a fine distinction between those words, and *too simple* has the same effective meaning.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ok thanks for the positive feedback!

Comment: Please visit the Help Center to see the sort of questions and answers expected on ELU. In particular, answers should be well researched and contain linked, attributed supporting references. Answers lacking such come over as (and may be) no more than one person's opinions.